# Keras Invalid argument of label data

Tags: keras, lstm

Attempt to train keras network with one LSTM layer for time series data classification returns this error:

```
Invalid argument: Specified a list with shape [1239,1] from a tensor with shape [310,1]
```

Here is part of the code:

```
trainset = trainset.reshape(1239, 600, 1)
testset = testset.reshape(310, 600, 1)

trainlabels = np.arange(0, len(trainset_idx), 1).reshape(1239, 1)
testlabels = np.arange(0, len(testset_idx), 1).reshape(310, 1)

model = Sequential()
model.add(LSTM(units=1239, activation='relu', batch_input_shape=(1239, 600, 1),
              stateful=False, return_sequences=False))

model.compile(loss='sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
              optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])

print(model.summary())
model.fit(trainset, trainlabels, validation_data=(testset, testlabels), 
          epochs=5, batch_size=1239)

scores = model.evaluate(testset, testlabels, verbose=0)
print("Accuracy: %.2f%%" % (scores[1]*100))
```

The data is basically spectrums, where all datapoints are evenly spaced and each sample contains 600 of them.

Has anyone encountered this error before or could advise what the issue could be?

Comment: Can you post the full stack trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the issue is that you specify `batch_input_shape` which causes the model to complain when you pass your test set which has only 310 entries. Simply change the line,

```
model.add(LSTM(units=1239, activation='relu', batch_input_shape=(1239, 600, 1),
              stateful=False, return_sequences=False))
```

to

```
model.add(LSTM(units=1239, activation='relu', input_shape=(600, 1),
              stateful=False, return_sequences=False))
```

This would get rid of the error. But I have some serious doubts about your approach. For example, you are using the output of the LSTM as a classification layer. This is quite unorthodox. You should consider using a Dense layer on top.

Few other things. Your model is very computationally hungry.

- You are using a batch size of 1239 to fit the model, which is the size of the training size. Instead, you should try a smaller batch size.
- Your LSTM has 1239 units. Even the most complex models I've seen in production uses few hundreds of units. So as I explained above, should consider using a Dense layer with 1239 outputs (if that's the number of classes) and reduce the size of your LSTM.

Comment: Thank you, this worked. You were right about inefficiency of this model, I will try adding Dense and Dropout layers for final model.